# Swift Cocoa - How to load system image "NSCaution" into NSImageView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview

I'm trying to load the system image called `NSCaution` programmatically.  I can easily load it with Interface Builder since it's one of the displayed options for NSImageView:

[image: nscaution system image]

However, the following code does not work. It always sets `img` to nil:

```
let img = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "NSCaution", accessibilityDescription: nil)
print(img?.name())
```

The [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/3622472-init) suggests "To look up the names of system symbol images, download the SF Symbols app from [Apple Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/)."  So, I downloaded that app and indeed `NSCaution` is not included.  That's probably why the above code does not work.  (Indeed, if I pick an image name like `pencil` that *is* included in the SF Symbols app, then the above code works.)

What code should I be using to load `NSCaution` programmatically instead of via Interface Builder?  The question is broader than just `NSCaution`; none of the `NSxxx` images are loadable with the above code.

Comment: The image in the image view is created with `NSImage(named:)`.

Answer (score 0):

A comment on the original question above solved the issue.  The corrected code is:

```
let img = NSImage(named: NSImage.cautionName)
```

Posting this as an answer for posterity.

Comment: Better use `NSImage.cautionName` instead of `"NSCaution"`.

Comment: Updated it.  Found a handy list referenced from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519835-cautionname?changes=_5.